Do optimistic rollups burn ETH?
I was reading Optimism's docs on Transaction Fees on OP Mainnet, and this part caught my attention:

Like Ethereum, OP Mainnet uses the EIP-1559 mechanism to set the base fee for transactions.

That made me wonder if Optimism burns ETH just like Ethereum Mainnet does?
My understanding is that all ETH minted on OP Mainnet comes from L1, i.e., it is ETH locked up in an L1 contract.
In order to keep the total supplies equal, OP Mainnet should NOT burn ETH in the style of EIP-1559. Right?

The "base fee" is useful for reducing/slowing down the spikes in the tx gas price at times when the network suddenly becomes congested (say, when a big company launches their Airdrop campaign - or when the crypto market is very volatile).
The burning of tx fees, however, can exist independently of the "base fee". Or not exist, for that matter.
The "keeping supplies equal" point from the OP sounds fair (although, L2s could circumvent this, given it's just them who controls the L2 block producing nodes/addresses and the L2 state contracts on the L1).
Another reason is that it's not the L2, but Ethereum/the whole ecosystem (of which the L2 is just a little fraction) who would benefit from the burning of the ETH on the L2. So, the L2 would, probably, prefer keeping the ETH from tx fees as profit, rather than burn it for the sake of the whole Ethereum ecosystem.
Therefore, I can see why L2s (like Optimism) would be interested in implementing the London-like "base fee" (to also have a more predictable and fair fee structure), but not the "base fee" burning, as well.

Makes sense, thanks for your answer. However, I don't think it's a matter of preference. Optimism simply cannot burn ETH. If they do, the balance of the rollup and of the L1 bridge contract would no longer be equal.
